# Change font-awesome icon onclick reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, font-awesome

I'm creating a navbar with React. I use burger menu and I want to change the bar menu to times on click currently I have following:

```
const {icons, setIcon} = useState('faBars');
...
<FontAwesomeIcon 
   icon={icons}
   onClick={() => {setIcon({faTimes})}}
/>
```

But obviously it doesn't work. I was wondering how can I correct the code.

Comment: should be like that: `const [icons, setIcon] = useState('faBars'); setIcon('faTimes')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the new value as a `string` as the following:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon 
   icon={icons}
   onClick={() => {setIcon('faTimes')}}
/>
```

The main problem could be you tried to pass as an object - `setIcon({faTimes})` - instead of a string based on the initial value in your `useState`.