# Toggle Fontawesome Icon onClick in React Project

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently using fontawesome in my project and I have a checklist for the user.

When the user marks one step as checked it's just for them and doesn't get saved anywhere.

**What I'd like to have** (edited in the browser for demonstration):

[image]

getting the checked element to be styled differently is already solved. I'm having issue with swapping the icon from my Fontawesome Component.

**Code:**

```
<ul className="ingredient-list">
  {doc.ingredients && doc.ingredients.map((ing, index) => (
    <li key={index} onClick={strike}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquare} className="icon" />
      <span className="blocked">{ing}</span>
    </li>
  ))} 
</ul>
```

the function strike looks something like this and only styles the li element including the childs.

```
const strike = (e) => {
   e.target.closest('li').classList.toggle('strike')
}
```

when printing the child to the console I'm unable to get the FontAwesomeIcon Component since it already rendered in the frontend to SVG.

I'm not sure, is there a way to actually manipulating the `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={} />` within the strike function?

[image]

Complete Rendered Code in the Frontend:

```
<div class="col">
    <h3>Zutaten</h3>
    <ul class="ingredient-list">
        <li>
            <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-square icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                <path
                    fill="currentColor"
                    d="M384 32C419.3 32 448 60.65 448 96V416C448 451.3 419.3 480 384 480H64C28.65 480 0 451.3 0 416V96C0 60.65 28.65 32 64 32H384zM384 80H64C55.16 80 48 87.16 48 96V416C48 424.8 55.16 432 64 432H384C392.8 432 400 424.8 400 416V96C400 87.16 392.8 80 384 80z"
                ></path>
            </svg>
            <span class="blocked">element 1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-square icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                <path
                    fill="currentColor"
                    d="M384 32C419.3 32 448 60.65 448 96V416C448 451.3 419.3 480 384 480H64C28.65 480 0 451.3 0 416V96C0 60.65 28.65 32 64 32H384zM384 80H64C55.16 80 48 87.16 48 96V416C48 424.8 55.16 432 64 432H384C392.8 432 400 424.8 400 416V96C400 87.16 392.8 80 384 80z"
                ></path>
            </svg>
            <span class="blocked">element 2</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-square icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                <path
                    fill="currentColor"
                    d="M384 32C419.3 32 448 60.65 448 96V416C448 451.3 419.3 480 384 480H64C28.65 480 0 451.3 0 416V96C0 60.65 28.65 32 64 32H384zM384 80H64C55.16 80 48 87.16 48 96V416C48 424.8 55.16 432 64 432H384C392.8 432 400 424.8 400 416V96C400 87.16 392.8 80 384 80z"
                ></path>
            </svg>
            <span class="blocked">element 3</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-square icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                <path
                    fill="currentColor"
                    d="M384 32C419.3 32 448 60.65 448 96V416C448 451.3 419.3 480 384 480H64C28.65 480 0 451.3 0 416V96C0 60.65 28.65 32 64 32H384zM384 80H64C55.16 80 48 87.16 48 96V416C48 424.8 55.16 432 64 432H384C392.8 432 400 424.8 400 416V96C400 87.16 392.8 80 384 80z"
                ></path>
            </svg>
            <span class="blocked">element 4</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can I see more of the rendered html code? but anything is possible, I don't actually know react but absolute worst case you could just remove the svg and manually add another fontawesome with javascript, but I have a feeling this must be possible a cleaner way than that

Comment: @Matthias wow, that would really suck to do so. I added the complete section of the site to the question above

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63112144/change-font-awesome-icon-onclick-reactjs) helps?

Comment: you could also just define both icons and then have one hidden and toggle the display. I'll post an answer how that could be, I think that should work

Comment: The best solution would be to make separate component for list item, that way it would be much easier to handle all logic including rendering of correct FontAwesome icon. If that's suitable for your application, I can write an answer on that.

Comment: Jovana's solution does sound like the proper one :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to just have both square and strike fonticons in the html and hide one of the two at all times. Something like this

```
<ul className="ingredient-list">
  {doc.ingredients && doc.ingredients.map((ing, index) => (
    <li key={index} onClick={strike}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquare} className="icon" />
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStrike} className="icon hidden"/>
      <span className="blocked">{ing}</span>
    </li>
  ))} 
</ul>
```

and then your javascript code:

```
const strike = (e) => {
    /* toggle .hidden class on both fontawesomes */
    var children = e.target.closest('li').querySelector('svg');
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        children[i].classList.toggle("hidden");
    }
}
```

and then in the css you have

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Note I haven't tested this and don't know react, so this is kinda also like pseudocode.

Comment: I did some adaption to the code. Aparently it was actually that easy and I could call them directly without targeting the svg (`e.target.closest('li').querySelector('.icon')`). thank you for your help. I am able to give you the bounty after 21 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to extract list item to separate component.

This is simple representation of `ListItem` component, but it does all the job. The text is passed as parameter, there is state which holds current state of item (checked or unchecked). Based on that state `<li>` can have class `strike` and render second FontAwesome icon (only if item is checked).

Since `ListItem` is now separate component, each item has its separate state, which makes it much easier to handle all logic referring to single item changes.

**ListItem.jsx**

```
const { useState } = require("react");

const ListItem = ({ ing }) => {
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  const toggleCheck = () => {
    setChecked((checked) => !checked);
    console.log(isChecked);
  };

  return (
    <li onClick={toggleCheck} className={isChecked && "strike"}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquare} className="icon" />
      {isChecked && <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStrike} className="icon" />}
      <span className="blocked">{ing}</span>
    </li>
  );
};

export default ListItem;
```

**Parent component** (the one holding entire list) would look like so:

```
<ul className="ingredient-list">
  {doc.ingredients && doc.ingredients.map((ing, index) => {
      return <ListItem ing={ing} key={index} />;
  })} 
</ul>
```